# How create an adjacency matrix of a Maze graph

Tags: graph, graph-algorithm, maze, adjacency-matrix, prims-algorithm

I'm working on making a maze Generator using Prim's Algorithm. I understand i have to make an undirected weighted graph and represent it on an Adjacency Matrix or List. i created the boolean[][] adjacenyMatrix array to show which edges currently exist in the maze. But i have an issue trying to implement the algorithm i thought of. Here is my code:

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the size of the maze");
    int mazeHeight = scanner.nextInt();
    int mazeWidth = scanner.nextInt();
    int noOfNodes = mazeHeight * mazeWidth;

    boolean[][] adjacencyMatrix = new boolean[noOfNodes][noOfNodes];


    for (int i = 0; i < mazeHeight; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < mazeWidth; j++ ) {
            // Edges exist from left to right
            adjacencyMatrix[i][j] = true;
            adjacencyMatrix[j][i] = true;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < mazeWidth; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < noOfNodes; j + mazeWidth) {  // <-----------I'm having an issue here; Not a statement
            // Edges exist from top to bottom
            adjacencyMatrix[i][j] = true;
            adjacencyMatrix[j][i] = true;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You don't need to actually construct an adjacency matrix.  When you generate the maze, Prim's algorithm is run on an *implicit* graph: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_graph

Answer (score 1):

After taking a break; i looked over it and realised that i forgot to include the "=" symbol >.<

so j += mazeWidth